# Nikah after zina

Tags: nikah, zina, halal-haram

I am a non muslim female that has been committing zina with a Male for many years. He was married and during our relationship has gotten divorced. Our relationship has resulted in the birth of a baby girl. I want to convert to islam and make nikah with him, however he has now told me that in order to make nikah we have to be apart for 6 months for every year that we have been together. Is this true or what would be the correct path from here

Comment: Why are you converting to Islam? Are you doing it for the sake of Allah or so you can marry him?

Comment: He has told me that this is the way forward however I think he may be just doing this for the benefits of a marriage. I do however want to being my child up the islamic way. He currently still lives with his ex wife as they have children together as well.

Comment: All this sounds blurry and unislamic. Once a Muslim is divorced his former wife is a foreign woman to him which he shouldn't see unveiled nor visit without the presence of a mahram, so staying with her is haraam and he should know this. So before asking you to separate etc. he should repent from his misdeed. While you as a non-Muslim should know that all your misdeeds will be cleared off once you become a Muslim so basically the person who needs to repent is him in first place. But maybe it is good to wait one (waiting) period and ask for forgiveness too assuming you want to be with this man.

Comment: So is it possible that he is not islamically divorced from her and he is lying to me about this? Is there anyway for me to find out? I want to be with him but it seems like he is just lying about everything

Answer (score 1):

After accepting Islam both of you must sincerely repent for your sin and you must cleanse your womb by observing istibra’ or ‘iddah, which is three menstrual cycles according to the longer duration. After doing that you may marry. There is no '6 months for every year' condition. For further information contact a qualified scholar in person.

Comment: Please consider supporting your claims by evidences. And read [answer].